# AWS Cognito - Sign Up Flow - Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate

Tags: amazon-web-services, next.js, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I have a very simple sign up form (email & password) that works fine until I try to add the new user to a user pool group. Here is my code; I am using Next.js with Typescript with AWS (Amplify / Cognito).

```
import { Auth, Hub } from 'aws-amplify';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { useState } from 'react';

const SignupForm = () => {
  const router = useRouter();
  const [formState, setFormState] = useState({
    email: '',
    password: '', // Initialize with an empty string
  });

  const handleChange = e => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setFormState(prevState => ({
      ...prevState,
      [name]: value,
    }));
  };

  const handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const { email, password } = formState;

      const signUpResponse = await Auth.signUp({
        username: email,
        password,
        attributes: {
          email,
        },
      });

      const user = signUpResponse.user;

      await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, {
        'cognito:groups': ['members'],
      });

      console.log('User added to the group:', userGroupResponse);

      router.push('/registered');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error registering user:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="email">
          Email
        </label>
        <input
          type="email"
          id="email"
          name="email"
          value={formState.email}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label htmlFor="password">
          Password
        </label>
        <input
          type="password"
          id="password"
          name="password"
          value={formState.password}
          onChange={handleChange}
          required
        />
      </div>
      <button type="submit">
        Register
      </button>
    </form>
  );
};

export default SignupForm;
```

Note that it is the

```
const user = signUpResponse.user;

      await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, {
        'cognito:groups': ['members'],
      });
```

That i can comment out and have no issues, but I want to add it to the user pool group 'members'. The error appears on the page as follows:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate

Source
src/components/signup/SignupForm.tsx (37:12) @ Auth

  35 | const user = signUpResponse.user;
  36 | 
> 37 | await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, {
     |      ^
  38 |   'cognito:groups': ['members'],
  39 | });
```

and in the console:

```
CognitoUser.js:1148 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate
    at CognitoUser.getSession (CognitoUser.js:1148:1)
    at eval (Auth.js:1652:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at AuthClass.eval (Auth.js:1651:1)
    at step (tslib.es6.js:100:1)
    at Object.eval [as next] (tslib.es6.js:81:46)
    at eval (tslib.es6.js:74:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at __awaiter (tslib.es6.js:70:1)
    at AuthClass._userSession (Auth.js:1637:25)
    at AuthClass.userSession (Auth.js:1708:1)
    at eval (Auth.js:1254:1)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at AuthClass.updateUserAttributes (Auth.js:1253:1)
    at handleSubmit (SignupForm.tsx:37:13)
```

I have checked my cognito settings and full read/write permissions are enabled. The user pool group 'members' exists. And the user is created without the user pool group code so I believe all aws-exports etc are correct. If no solution is found I may have to add a group as an attribute instead though this is not ideal.

I believe it may be possible by setting up a lambda function to add the user to the group after signup, but it would be surprise me if this is the recommended method as it seems more complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly "[Amazon Cognito / Signing up and confirming user accounts](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/signing-up-users-in-your-app.html)", after a user signs up, they are typically confirmed either manually by an admin, or automatically via email or SMS code, depending on your configuration.

[image: When users enter the confirmation code, they automatically verify email or phone -- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/images/cognito/latest/developerguide/images/amazon-cognito-sign-in-confirm-user.png]

After confirmation, the user then needs to sign in to start a session. Once signed in, their ID token is available and user attributes can be updated.

But in your case, `Auth.updateUserAttributes()` is trying to access the current authenticated session of the user, which does not exist yet immediately after sign up. The user needs to be signed in before the session is available, and user attributes can be updated.
Hence, an error like `Local storage is missing an ID Token, Please authenticate`

When you sign up a user, they are not automatically signed in.
Therefore, if you want to update user attributes right after sign up, you have two options:

1. **Sign the user in immediately after sign up:** (at least for testing if it is working)
   This will start a session and make the ID token available.
   Your `handleSubmit` function would be, for instance:

```js
const handleSubmit = async e => {
  e.preventDefault();

  try {
    const { email, password } = formState;

    const signUpResponse = await Auth.signUp({
      username: email,
      password,
      attributes: {
        email,
      },
    });

    // Sign the user in after sign up
    const signInResponse = await Auth.signIn(email, password);

    const user = signInResponse.user;

    await Auth.updateUserAttributes(user, {
      'cognito:groups': ['members'],
    });

    console.log('User added to the group:', userGroupResponse);

    router.push('/registered');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error registering user:', error);
  }
};
```

I mentioned "at least for testing", because this approach may be a security concern: it automatically signs in the user after registration without any confirmation.

2. **Use a post-confirmation trigger:** You can use AWS Lambda to add a trigger that runs after a user is confirmed. This trigger could add the user to the group. This approach is safer than the previous one, as it does not involve automatically signing in the user after sign up. If you choose this option, you would need to set up an AWS Lambda function and configure Cognito to call it after user confirmation.

You can see an example in "**[How do I automatically confirm users in Amazon Cognito?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cognito-automatically-confirm-users)**"

The short description is:

> When a user sign ups with an Amazon Cognito user pool, they generally must have their email address or phone number verified.
> This is usually done by sending an OTP to a user's email address or phone number for verification.
> A user can also be automatically confirmed without OTP verification.
>
> These are the high-level steps to automatically confirm a user without using an OTP with the user's email address or phone number:
>
> - Create an AWS Lambda function.
> - Create an Amazon Cognito user pool with a pre sign-up Lambda trigger.
> - Sign up the user in Amazon Cognito. Verify the user attributes by using the AWS Management Console or an AWS API.